# Slow Down Mod_Flite TTS in Freeswitch

Tags: debian, voip, freeswitch

I am working with Freeswitch on a debian server. I have an XML file which Flite reads from when someone calls the phone line.

The problem is that she reads it just a little too fast.

Is there a configuration setting to slow down the speech engine or a hack I can add into the text to make her slow down a little.

I found an answer [HERE](https://github.com/bfoz/flite) but it seems that they are relying on a `./bin/flite` command which does not exist for me.

Any Ideas?

Comment: To whoever up voted - I was not able to find a fix, but I selected a voice that was a little slower (Allison)  then added a bunch of commas and semi-colons. Not ideal but good enough